# Is it possible to form an indented code block with a single parenthesis and <CR>?

Tags: vim

If I enter `{` in vim and hit enter I want it to form a block as below:

```
function name(args) {
     |
}
```

or this:

```
function name(args) 
{
     |
}
```

**Update**: I had it working with delimitMate, but I now found out that the problem seem to have occurred when I installed supertab.

Github Issue: https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/issues/66

I haven't resolved the issue yet, any Ideas? Alternative to the above plugins?

Answer (score 1):

These are the settings I have in my `.vimrc` for that:

```
" Turn on syntax highlighting and auto-indenting
syntax enable
filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
```

I also use [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540); Input the keyword, hit Tab, get an entire function, loop, etc. block for the language you're working in. Saves some typing.

Comment: I have tried setting like that as I had `filetype plugin indent on` but no luck.

Comment: Personally, although indent helped, I really got cranking with `snipMate`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard feature of most Vim's snippet plugins (just search for *snippet* on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org) and pick your favourite). [Snipmate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) has long been one of the most popular ones, and easy to configure and add new ones (snippets, that it).

Answer (score 1):

Go lo-tech with:

```
inoremap {<CR> <CR><CR>}<C-o>k<Tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

and the file you're editing has the right extension (I guess `.js`), then automatic indentation should work out of the box.

Comment: I do have that in `.vimrc` and I don't mean just `.js` was trying to give a generic example.

Comment: @saint What about the file extension? If the file type isn't correctly identified, the identation won't be correctly applied.

Comment: it does identify the file, I have it set to show in status line.